# Selenium- Click a button issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

[image]

using imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

using this def to navigate to the exact iFrame that the button is under :

```
def changeIframetoManagement():
    wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait2.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "moduleManagement")))
```

my attempt to achieve that task :

```
changeIframetoManagement()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.bootbox.modal.fade.show-order-info-bootbox- 
container.in > div > div > div.modal-body > button").click()
```

im also tried to reach by xPath like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/button").click()
```

that is the last i frame i was in

```
def changeIframetoOrders():
   wait3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
   wait3.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 
   "orderInfo")))
```

[image: this is the last i frame i was in]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After switching into the iframe try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.modal-dialog button.bootbox-close-button").click()
```

**UPD**
According to your last comments, since you previously switched into iframe located by `orderInfo` name, before switching into iframe located by `moduleManagement` id you have yo switch to the default content, like this:

```
changeIframetoOrders()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
changeIframetoManagement()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-dialog button.bootbox-close-button"))).click()
```

Comment: got a trace back also as i mention on the above answer

Comment: So your problem not with the button. Problem is with switching to the iframe

Comment: I edited the question so you can see the last iFrame i was in maybe you can see there , to sum up my button is in the moduleManagement iframe and not in the Orderinfo one i use the Def's above to switch between . maybe i got something worng there , anyway thank you very much

Comment: So, you were inside the orderInfo iframe and you trying to switch to modalManagement iframe directly from there, right? If so you first need to switch to the default content from the first iframe and only after that switch to the second iframe!

Comment: BTW, you don't need to define separate wait instance for each method. You can define one global wait instead.

Comment: Allright ill test it thank you and you got maybe an idea how i make this wait global?

Comment: Just define the wait below the line you defining the driver with the same indentation.

Answer (score 1):

See if this xpath works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(@class,'close-button')]").click()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  <module>
    changeIframetoManagement()
   changeIframetoManagement
    wait2.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "moduleManagement")))
  File "C:\Users\Benco\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Btw i must notice that before i switch again to that iframe i was on other iframe , maybe the transition is somehow problematic?

Answer (score 1):

The x button is in **moduleManagement** iframe.

and the goal is to click on it using Selenium.

as per OP

```
wait3.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 
   "orderInfo")))
```

looks like he was in a different iframe `orderInfo`.

So I would suggest whenever you are done with any iframe stuff, always switch the control back to default content like below :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Now again you will have to switch to `moduleManagement` iframe like below  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "moduleManagement")))
```

and click on x button like this  :

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, ''bootbox-close-button) and text()='x']"))).click()
```